# Vague question re "Bad file descriptor" in Flask with Peewee/pscopg2

Tags: python, postgresql, peewee

tl;dr: An app that had been working fine is suddenly throwing a "Bad file descriptor" error with no other changes; I need advice for how to evaluate this.

I inherited an app that had been untouched for years, after the server crashed and I needed to move it to another machine. It's built with Flask, and uses Peewee to talk to a Postgres database over pyscopg2. It has a bunch of other stuff--an Elasticsearch engine for searching, a lot of heavy JS on the front end--but that doesn't seem to be the problem here. The code is moderately complex, and I am not very knowledgeable about all of its pieces.

It took me a while to get it set up using the sketchy deployment instructions that had been left behind, but eventually I got it running, and was able to get a test version running on a clean VM and then deploy it on an actual server, using gunicorn and nginx. It's been working fine in production for a week. I'm using Debian Buster for all versions. I'm using the most recent versions of all software.

I then decided to do some basic code cleanup, and ran the entire app through a linter, before looking at some other changes to make, that the end user had requested. Unfortunately, after this, the app consistently fails at the same point with a "Bad file descriptor" error. This is in a pre-run section, which parses a large XML file and saves the info to the database and to Elasticsearch; the app receives an XML upload, forks a few processes, and runs the parse/index process in the background.

I am subsequently unable to get past this error by any means. I have launched a clean VM and installed everything from scratch; I've reverted the git repo to before I linted the code. Same problem. I don't see how it can be a code issue, as it's now at the same point it was when I started. But I'm at a loss for what to do, and terrified that the production machine will fail.

The errors I get (trimming the first few lines that refer to places in the app itself) are:

```
[2021-03-14 14:40:11.699837]     self.execute()
[2021-03-14 14:40:11.699878]   File "/home/deploy/git/myapp/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/peewee.py", line 1906, in inner
[2021-03-14 14:40:11.699907]     return method(self, database, *args, **kwargs)
[2021-03-14 14:40:11.699946]   File "/home/deploy/git/myapp/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/peewee.py", line 1977, in execute
[2021-03-14 14:40:11.699976]     return self._execute(database)
[2021-03-14 14:40:11.700004]   File "/home/deploy/git/myapp/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/peewee.py", line 2149, in _execute
[2021-03-14 14:40:11.700032]     cursor = database.execute(self)
[2021-03-14 14:40:11.700060]   File "/home/deploy/git/myapp/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/peewee.py", line 3156, in execute
[2021-03-14 14:40:11.700088]     return self.execute_sql(sql, params, commit=commit)
[2021-03-14 14:40:11.700115]   File "/home/deploy/git/myapp/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/peewee.py", line 3150, in execute_sql
[2021-03-14 14:40:11.700143]     self.commit()
[2021-03-14 14:40:11.700171]   File "/home/deploy/git/myapp/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/peewee.py", line 2916, in __exit__
[2021-03-14 14:40:11.700198]     reraise(new_type, new_type(exc_value, *exc_args), traceback)
[2021-03-14 14:40:11.700226]   File "/home/deploy/git/myapp/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/peewee.py", line 190, in reraise
[2021-03-14 14:40:11.700254]     raise value.with_traceback(tb)
[2021-03-14 14:40:11.700282]   File "/home/deploy/git/myapp/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/peewee.py", line 3143, in execute_sql
[2021-03-14 14:40:11.700309]     cursor.execute(sql, params or ())
[2021-03-14 14:40:11.700339] OperationalError('SSL SYSCALL error: Bad file descriptor\n')
127.0.0.1 - - [14/Mar/2021 10:40:11] "POST /manage/versions/upload HTTP/1.1" 500 -
Error on request:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/deploy/git/myapp/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 323, in run_wsgi
    execute(self.server.app)
  File "/home/deploy/git/myapp/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 315, in execute
    write(data)
  File "/home/deploy/git/myapp/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 273, in write
    self.send_response(code, msg)
  File "/home/deploy/git/myapp/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 388, in send_response
    self.wfile.write(hdr.encode("ascii"))
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/socketserver.py", line 799, in write
    self._sock.sendall(b)
OSError: [Errno 9] Bad file descriptor
Exception in thread Thread-22:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/threading.py", line 917, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/threading.py", line 865, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/socketserver.py", line 654, in process_request_thread
    self.shutdown_request(request)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/socketserver.py", line 509, in shutdown_request
    self.close_request(request)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/socketserver.py", line 513, in close_request
    request.close()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/socket.py", line 420, in close
    self._real_close()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/socket.py", line 414, in _real_close
    _ss.close(self)
OSError: [Errno 9] Bad file descriptor
```

I note that the final section ("Exception in thread Thread-22") is showing the system Python, rather than my virtual environment; I don't know if that's relevant, or if that's just what's running some overall process. I didn't get to this point doing anything different, though--the app is running in the virtual environment.

I'd be very grateful for any thoughts here--I'm obviously hoping it's some kind of stupid permission error or something, as I can't easily go into the code because of its complexity.

Comment: So when you moved what if any where changes to OS(&version), Postgresql version, etc? The traceback starts with a SSL error which is also mentioned in this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22435764/ssl-syscall-error-bad-file-descriptor-using-sqlalchemy-and-postgres) post, does anything there ring a bell?

Comment: OS and version are the same, as is Postgresql version. Originally, I used the existing `requirements.txt` file for versions, but there were too many problems with things not installing, so I tried just installing the most recent version using pip, and that's what's working on the live system. So I believe these are the same. I did see that SO post but I couldn't see anything connected. The database-handling stuff in the app is rather more complicated than I'd feel comfortable messing around with. (I know this was not a helpful response :-( )

Comment: I did just try to wipe out the virtual environment and reinstall everything using the `requirements.txt` versions (except for the one or two problematic ones), but got the same result.

Comment: Alright, so what are the OS, Postgresql and Python versions(update your question with this)? I am not understanding the `requirements.txt` part. Probably easiest is to a `diff` between the `pip freeze` of the production setup and the problem setup. Again update the question with this information.

Comment: (Exploring an issue related to this; it seems that there is in fact a discrepancy between the version running on the live site, and the most recently git commit to master. Trying to figure this out.)